# KELP cannot find package...build failed

Tags: kelp

When I'm trying to build the binaries using:
./scripts/build.sh 
I have this error: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error it seems your *go* directory structure is incorrect.
You need to clone the git repo in this directory:

- `$GOPATH/src/github.com/lightyeario/kelp`

Make sure your *$GOPATH* is set up correctly: `echo $GOPATH`

---

Before you compile the binary with the build script, you will need to install the dependencies using [glide](https://glide.sh/)

- `curl https://glide.sh/get | sh`.

Once you have set up glide, you can run `glide install` to install the dependencies specified in the *glide.yaml* file. This will create a *vendor* directory which will be used to find the packages needed to compile the binary.

Once this is all set up, you can invoke the build script

- `./scripts/build.sh`

Comment: Yes the problem was in $GOPATH. After I clone clone the git repo in this directory:

"$GOPATH/src/github.com/lightyeario/kelp" -  it  BUILD SUCCESSFUL